# How to use python.mechanize to find the url that AJAX page is redirected to after the execution?

Tags: python, mechanize

After an AJAX page code is executed, the browser would open a different url (specified with `window.location.href`). How can I fetch it using mechanize?

```
import mechanize
response = mechanize.urlopen(url)
return response.geturl()
```

would return the initial url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mechanize doesn't handle Javascript. Try using [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) instead